# Which strains of C. diphteria are causing Diphteria toxin?

Tags: microbiology, homework, bacteriology

I got this question:

**Diphteria toxin is produced only by those strains of C. diphtheria that have which of the following characteristics?**

1. Encapsulated
2. glucose fermenters
3. lysogenic for b-prophage
4. only mitis-strains
5. sucrose fermenters

I think the right answer is **lysogenic for b-prophage**, since Freeman found out that toxic gene is encoded by lysogenic phage infecting all toxigenic strains in 1951.
However, I am not sure what "b-" means in "b-prophage".

**Which part is "b-" in Prophage?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real simple: Beta!  Often called "[phage beta](http://textbookofbacteriology.net/phage_2.html)" b-prophage is a more modern way to write it.  I knew that one off the top of my head, but I like to refer the general public interested in bacteriology to [Tadar's online text.](http://textbookofbacteriology.net/index.html)

It's nicely done, and I wish that it had been around when I was studying bacteriology.

Specific to your question:

> Hence, Corynebacterium diphtheriae can only produce the toxin
>   responsible for the disease if it carries a temperate virus called
>   phage beta. Only lysogenized streptococci  produce the erythrogenic
>   toxin (pyrogenic exotoxin) which causes the skin rash of scarlet
>   fever; and some  botulinum toxins are synthesized only by lysogenized
>   strains of C. botulinum.